# Hacking in move semantics for Boost 1.54 MultiIndex?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working on a project where we've chosen to use the Boost::MultiIndex container. It's cool, I like it. However, we're having an issue on the build targets with Boost 1.54, because in that version the container does not support move semantics of elements. This is a problem, because the elements have a noncopyable member. This means they, too, are noncopyable implicitly.

I could provide a complete example, but this is really a best-practices question, not a particulars problem:

```
class ContainerElement
{
public:
   someMethods()
   ...

private:
  NonCopyableEvent event;
};
```

And we have the problem class:

```
class NonCopyableEvent : noncopyable
{
private:
  /* some project-specific stuff regarding the global scheduler. */
};
```

Okay, so the three main strategies I have are:

1. **Drop support for Boost 1.54.** I think this is a valid suggestion because the version of MultiIndex in it is very old, and we really oughtn't use it.
2. **Retroactively add a compiler-conditional to remove that non-copyable status.** Doing this would mean that I needed to be careful about the semantics of the copy.
3. **Hack the copy constructor of `ContainerElement` to copy everything, but move the `NonCopyableEvent`.** This I also don't like, for similar reasons to above.

The main concerns are that the event refers to a global thing, and copying that event would be totally unacceptable. Can someone give some design guidance here?

Comment: *"Drop support for Boost 1.54"* That's what I would do as a dev, but the customers sometimes have a different idea about those things. :) That being said, the version we are talking about *is* almost 4 years old and boost is not hard to upgrade, so depending on who your users are this certainly is something to at least consider.

Comment: I already put the question to one of the platform managers, and his response was essentially "this is part of the target platform, so we cannot do it." Bah.